# The correct way of chaining tasks using Continuation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

The `async`-`await` concept is easy to understand, However, I have trouble to master `ContinueWith`.

In the following example, I want to run 2 async tasks (LoadAsync and ComputeAsync) one after another, and in the meanwhile, I want to DoSomethingElse.  Method #1 is the approach I am familiar with.

Are Methods #2, #3, and #4 correct for achieving the same result as #1?  Could someone please explain/comment on what are the differences behind the scene?  Thanks!

Method #1 - Use `await` inside an `async` function

```
public async int LoadAndComputeAsync
{ 
    var data = await LoadAsync();
    return await ComputeAsync(data);
}

Task<int> task1 = LoadAndComputeAsync();
DoSomethingElse();
int result = await task1;
```

Method #2 - Execute synchronously in `Task.Run`

```
Task<int> task2 = Task.Run(() => {
    var data = LoadAsync().Result;
    return ComputeAsync(data).Result;
});
DoSomethingElse();
int result = await task2;
```

Method #3 - Use `ContinueWith` with `async` and `Unwrap`

```
Task<int> task3 = LoadAsync().ContinueWith(async(t) => {
    var data = t.Result;
    return await ComputeAsync(data);
}).Unwrap();
DoSomethingElse();
int result = await task3;
```

Method #4 - Execute synchronously in `ContinueWith`

```
Task<int> task4 = LoadAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
    var data = t.Result;
    return ComputeAsync(data).Result;
});
DoSomethingElse();
int result = await task4;
```

Comment: You should use `ContinueWith()` for chaining which will continue on the same task which is what you are doing

Comment: It is ok to use `Task.Result` when you are sure that `Task` has completed but still getting result using `await` is recommended.

Comment: This should also be added (`Task.Result` free) `Task<int> task3 = LoadAsync().ContinueWith(async (tsk) => await ComputeAsync(await tsk)).Unwrap();`

Comment: Why are you seeking alternatives to method #1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I have trouble to master `ContinueWith`.

The easiest way to use `ContinueWith` is spelled "await".

No, seriously. [`ContinueWith` is a low-level API with surprising default behavior](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). It will make your code more complex and much more difficult to maintain, while providing no benefit. So my question is "why?"

That said, the following will give you some answers, but these are intended for *instructional purposes only* and *not* production code.

First, `Task<T>.Result` has different exception handling behavior; it will wrap all exceptions in an `AggregateException` instead of raising them directly. This is because `Task<T>` was originally designed for parallel programming, not asynchronous programming; but when `async`/`await` were added, Microsoft decided to just reuse the existing `Task`/`Task<T>` types instead of creating a more asynchronous-native type. For asynchronous code, replace `.Result` with `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Next, `async` doesn't queue work to the thread pool. `Task.Run` does. So that's another difference for Method #2.

Your Method #3 is pretty close. If you replace `.Result` with `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, you'll still have the problem of the `TaskScheduler` used by `ContinueWith`, which defaults to `TaskScheduler.Current`, which may not be what you want (in asynchronous code, it's usually not). You should never use `ContinueWith` without specifying a `TaskScheduler`. Also, it's weird to use `ContinueWith` with `async` - why not just do Method #1 if you're using `async` anyway?

Method #4 does block a thread in the `ContinueWith`.

If you want to have a true reproduction of Method #1, you'll need to:

1. Prevent exceptions from being wrapped in `AggregateException`.
2. Always pass an explicit `TaskScheduler` to `ContinueWith`.
3. Use other appropriate flags for `ContinueWith` to make its behavior more async-friendly.
4. Capture the appropriate context and execute continuations in that context.

Here's an example:

```
// Original
public async Task<int> LoadAndComputeAsync()
{ 
  var data = await LoadAsync();
  return await ComputeAsync(data);
}

// Using ContinueWith
public Task<int> LoadAndComputeTheHardWayAsync()
{
  var scheduler = SynchronizationContext.Current != null ?
      TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() : TaskScheduler.Current;
  return LoadAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
      {
        var data = t.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return ComputeAsync(data);
      },
      CancellationToken.None,
      TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
      scheduler).Unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Well, it's still not a full equivalent, because an exception thrown in the `ContinueWith` delegate after getting a result won't be caught in a higher level construction unlike 'async' generated code.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov: Yup, forgot the `return` statement. Fixed.

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks for the explanation and sample code.  I don't want to do Method #1 because I have many different ComputeAsync functions for different types of data.  Creating an `async` function for each type of ComputeAsync seems to be messy.

Comment: @Tony: Method #1 will be a lot less messy than any other approach. Perhaps your best solution would be to pass a delegate to an `async` method?

Answer (score 0):

1. Most difference between method #2 and others it created thread by Task.Run
   async/await never creates a new thread - it executes the continuation on the same thread it was called from.
2. Method #1 and Method #3 almost same approach

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/#BKMK_Threads

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/#BKMK_AsyncandAwait

Comment: Well to be more specific: "async/await never creates a new thread" it depends because async/await is just a wrapper around any asynchronous mechanism you'd like use inside it can be async I/O which doesn't create a thread but can be anything else wrapped by awaiter and awaitable and can create threads inside (like Task Run does). Next: "it executes the continuation on the same thread it was called from" - only in cases of specific synchronization context, in other cases the continuations will be in other threads. And finally async/await and ContinueWith are totally different mechanisms.

Comment: 1. I agree with you, but my answer was specific to provided code.  2. Async/awit different mechanism, but according to context of the question it try achieve same result.

Comment: The answers should be accurate regardless of context they are supposed to cover or explicitly specify the caveats. In the question the author is asking about differences "behind the scene" so internal differences are important for him and apart of that they even aren't the same from the using perspective, for example exception handling aspects are different.